# Create ContentType for InfoPath forms

Tags: development, infopath

I have a form library in a site template. When I create a new site based on my template, I want to have the columns in the list like when I deploy my form from InfoPath.

Can I make a content type and a list definition for that? If so: what is the base content type? I have no clue.

When I save my template site (wsp) and take the list definition from there it won't work (forms/allitems.aspx not found).